# How to make multiple homescreens in an android app?

Tags: android

In my app i have 10 buttons on the opening screen , that is , the main screen. I want to distribute these buttons on different screens in the same app. In other words, i want to make three homescreens in my app and have buttons on them for three different types of tasks. just like we have homescreens in the mobile UI, i want to make them in my app just when it is opened. the three screens should be accessible by just touching the screen and holding it and moving it right or left. Does anyone know how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

You could put three different views in a viewflipper, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html, and then trigger the flipping with a gesture detector, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html

Answer (score 0):

Start normally by navigating to `File–>New–>Project–>Android Project`. In package explorer you can find your all projects in workspace. Select your current project to view its hierarchy. Open `res` folder and select `layout` folder. You will find `main.xml` already there by default which is the user interface or layout of the application. To create another layout, Right click on `layout` folder and Go to `New–>Other–>Android XML file`. Give a name and another layout file(xml) file will be created alongwith `main.xml`. You can design this new xml file as you design `main.xml`.

Now this newly created layout or user interface can be used in two ways. These are:

In the same class itself by using the following syntax:

`setContentView(R.layout.ms1); //where ms1 is the name of new layout`

For sample code for the project you can visit my website [article](http://jannatyahan.com/android-application-development-tutorial-for-making-mutiple-screens/).